# brew update and or brew doctor throwing errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, homebrew

When I try `brew update`, I get the following error. How can I fix it

```
~$ brew update
Error: undefined method `close!' for nil:NilClass
Please report this bug:
    https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/share/doc/homebrew/Troubleshooting.md#troubleshooting
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/extend/pathname.rb:129:in `ensure in atomic_write'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/extend/pathname.rb:129:in `atomic_write'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/cmd/untap.rb:42:in `unlink_tap_formula'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/cmd/update.rb:24:in `update'
/usr/local/Library/brew.rb:136:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the exact issue closed on `homebrew` github repo [brew update gives NilClass error](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/32807).

So here's how I got it working:

- Full uninstall of brew. For me I just wiped my /usr/local directory
  as this is a clean machine at the moment.
- Full uninstall of RVM.
- Make sure my command line tools are up to date "xcode-select --install"
- su to admin account and install Homebrew
- update /usr/local and all sub files/dirs to have my account as owner - "sudo chown -R jmcdonald ."
- "brew install ..." for all of these RVM/Ruby required libs: autoconf,
  automake, libtool, apple-gcc42, libyaml, libxslt, libksba, openssl
  (apple-gcc42 gave me errors but doesn't seem to have impact).
- Exit su and install RVM.
- Install a ruby: "rvm install 1.9.3"

I would guess I could have gotten it working without removals but wanted to make sure I had a clean setup.

Comment: ~$ RUBYOPT= RUBYLIB= brew update
-bash: /usr/local/bin/brew: No such file or directory

Comment: rm -rf /usr/local/Cellar /usr/local/.git && brew cleanup
(permission denied) for uninstalling homebrew, as I didn't go the route of http://superuser.com/questions/203707/how-to-uninstall-homebrew-osx-package-manager

Comment: no, for permission denied instructions (from my answer)

Comment: I'll follow the instructions given -